# Подключение мобильного приложения java к БД mysql

Tags: java, android, mysql, база-данных, android-studio

Как подключить мобильное java-приложение к удаленной базе данных MySQL, находящейся на удаленном сервере, и вывести весь список записей таблицы 'post'. Нужно решение на базе Android studio?

Comment: напишите сервер на спринге и обращайтесь к нему

Comment: Сервер уже есть на php. Это сайт. Api не планирую использовать, хотел бы прямые запросы применять

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужна серверная часть, которая будет принимать запросы с Android и отправлять SQL запросы к БД и возвращать результаты этих операций (например в Json) в Android.

Также можно использовать jdbc, но это небезопасно

Comment: лучше хибер:)))

Comment: @Санаев что такое хибер?

Comment: Hibernate - ORM

Comment: Сервер уже есть на php. Это сайт. Api не планирую использовать, хотел бы прямые запросы применять

Comment: Не мудрите, если есть api, то просто используйте библиотеку retrofit